# Changing only one value HSL

Tags: java

This is the current code I am using to change the Hue, Saturation, and Lightness of an image. How I would go about only changing just the Saturation or Lightness without adding a hue? Or how do I find the current hue value of the pixel so I can just use that?

```
    public static final int MAX_COLOR = 256;

    private final float LUMINANCE_RED = 0.2126f;
    private final float LUMINANCE_GREEN = 0.7152f;
    private final float LUMINANCE_BLUE = 0.0722f;

    private double hue = 180;
    private double saturation = 50;
    private double lightness = 0;

    private int[] lum_red_lookup;
    private int[] lum_green_lookup;
    private int[] lum_blue_lookup;

    private int[] final_red_lookup;
    private int[] final_green_lookup;
    private int[] final_blue_lookup;

    public void doHSB(double t_hue, double t_sat, double t_bri, BufferedImage image)
    {
        hue = t_hue;
        saturation = t_sat;
        lightness = t_bri;
        doInit();
        doColorize(image);
    }
    private void doInit()
    {
        lum_red_lookup = new int[MAX_COLOR];
        lum_green_lookup = new int[MAX_COLOR];
        lum_blue_lookup = new int[MAX_COLOR];

        double temp_hue = hue / 360f;
        double temp_sat = saturation / 100f;

        final_red_lookup = new int[MAX_COLOR];
        final_green_lookup = new int[MAX_COLOR];
        final_blue_lookup = new int[MAX_COLOR];

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COLOR; ++i)
        {
            lum_red_lookup[i] = (int) (i * LUMINANCE_RED);
            lum_green_lookup[i] = (int) (i * LUMINANCE_GREEN);
            lum_blue_lookup[i] = (int) (i * LUMINANCE_BLUE);

            double temp_light = (double) i / 255f;

            Color color = new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB((float) temp_hue, (float) temp_sat, (float) temp_light));

            final_red_lookup[i] = (int) (color.getRed());
            final_green_lookup[i] = (int) (color.getGreen());
            final_blue_lookup[i] = (int) (color.getBlue());
        }
    }

    private void doColorize(BufferedImage image)
    {
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int width;

        while (height-- != 0)
        {
            width = image.getWidth();

            while (width-- != 0)
            {
                Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(width, height), true);

                int lum = lum_red_lookup[color.getRed()] + lum_green_lookup[color.getGreen()] + lum_blue_lookup[color.getBlue()];

                if (lightness > 0)
                {
                    lum = (int) ((double) lum * (100f - lightness) / 100f);
                    lum += 255f - (100f - lightness) * 255f / 100f;
                }
                else if (lightness < 0)
                {
                    lum = (int) (((double) lum * (lightness + 100f)) / 100f);
                }
                Color final_color = new Color(final_red_lookup[lum], final_green_lookup[lum], final_blue_lookup[lum], color.getAlpha());
                image.setRGB(width, height, final_color.getRGB());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of posting *all* your code, can you just post the relevant part(s)? Thanks!

Comment: Edited. But all I took out was the constructor and the class declaration. That's as short as I can get it and have it still work. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HSL Color](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/hsl-color/) class allows you to adjust each property separately.

Comment: That will help a lot. Thanks.